# Wordpress as CMS: How to manage/handle images assigned to a post as full-sized background images in a slideshow?

Tags: posts, functions, images, javascript, gallery

I wonder if Wordpress is the best CMS or solution for what I wannt to do?

I need to find some way to upload images to a post that I can loop as background images. Just like I can upload multiple images and Wordpress automatically creates a `gallery` I don't want that to happen, but use those images directly (without any thumbnails or whatsoever) and be able to create a javascript slideshow that loops through those images.

So actually I probably need some way of creating a javascript array within php when I upload images to a post. And when viewing the post I can then loop through this array with javascript.

Any idea how to write a function that does that? 
However I might need single images inside the post - just no galleries.

Ideas on that? Tipps or tricks? Is there probably a plugin out there that does that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that within the loop using `wp_get_attachment_image`.

Something like (not tested):

```
//loop starts

//values for get_posts ( or wp query if you prefer)
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',  //gets the attachments aka your images
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

// some attributes you want added to each image   
$default_attr = array(
   'class'  => "background-attachment", //for your javascript
   'alt'   =>  'something',
   'title' => ''something
);

//loops through the attachments,
//uses the 'full' parameter assuming you want the default large image
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
         echo wp_get_attachment_image($attachment->ID, 'full', false, $default_attr);
    }
}

//loop ends
//your javascript for full page background via wp_enqueue_script
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this plugin will do the trick: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-supersized/

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation. Links only answers will be flagged as "poor quality" by the "community user" bot.

Comment: I don't get it - the plugin does *exactly* what the poster asked for. What other explanation is needed?

Comment: The system of the SE network (this "problem" is on all sites here on SE) considers itself to _not_ be a link sharing engine/extended google. So the bot flags such questions pretty quickly to force you to add more info. For example: "How to use the plugin", "What the plugin exactly does", "The plugin is coded well/crappy".